# How do I create texture that resembles texture of human body?

Tags: modeling, node-editor, rigging

Right now my human model looks way too smooth, in cycles render.  I prefer the bumpier look of Blender render, but I want to use cycles.  How can I create a bumpier, lumpier-looking human, something that looks more lifelike? Specifically, I want my good-natured wise man character to have a lumpy belly that ripples when he laughs! I am currently using diffuse BSDF node and a little bit of glossy BSDF node.  Thank you for help!

Edit: 
In response to atomicbezierslinger: I wanted to go ahead and say that yes, I do mean a protruding round belly, with slight rippling and dimpling, just enough to look like lifelike. This is the closest I've come to finding a photo reference, I hope this is not an inappropriate photo. [image: See here how the belly is slightly dimpled and lumpy.]

Just slight dimpling and lumpiness.  I will see if i can find a better reference photo.

Since you mentioned it, I would also like to know how to create fat folds that move realistically; that would come in handy for another character.  I appreciate all help and I will look into the SSS Shader.

Comment: Please place an image in your writing above to make it easier for others to help.  By lumpy do you mean a protruding round belly, ..... or folds of fat, or many protrusions such as in 1 inch size protrusions on a 5 foot human.  Or something else?

Comment: sssshader is for you

Comment: It is unfortunate yet no wisemanbellyripple modifier available in 2.75a  only available if plug-ons. but also hard even so still. If your human wanting lifelike, best of things you had better do is studying actual jolly-mans lifelike bellyripple. How many hours you spent watching really belly ripple?  I bet nothing! You post an question showing not anything research! how you are gonna use a stacksexchange not even have some sense to study a bellyriple first beforehand ; and various individual having to instruct you "use an sssshader" because you doesnt know even that!! what's?!!

Comment: To Mentalist: I have spent many hours examining my own rippling belly, but this does not reveal the secrets of the elusive Blender.  I have far to go.

Comment: @WishyQ, creating realistic skin or anything realistic for that matter is a pretty hard task. It involves many layers of work on modeling, shading, texturing, lighting, rendering and post production. I doubt you'll be able to get a thorough answer to your question here (unless someone makes you a several hour long video tutorial or 50 page long answer). I'd suggest you look for tutorials and courses for realistic human sculpting, texturing, shading and rendering. I'd start with https://cgcookie.com/courses/

Comment: Ha! Okay, so you were serious? I'm sorry, I really thought you were trolling us all with this question because it wasn't clear if you were asking about skin texture, modeling, or the render engine, and you described your character by his personality ("good-natured") which is totally subjective.

Comment: Anyway, for the dimpling use a combination of a Displace Modifier and some bump in your material. For the skin material add an SSS Shader to your glossy+diffuse mix. A skin texture image into the Diffuse color input would help too. For the ripple you can use a Cloth sim like in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1lHca7I3So or a Soft Body sim like in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KuzIDG4z_Gk Finally here is a Soft Body tutorial specifically for belly ripple, lol - although it is in Spanish: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DiO52a-iK_k Good luck!

Comment: To Mentalist:  Many thanks for your helpful suggestions!  I will probably be able to achieve my goals using this information.  If not fully achieve, at least a good start.

Comment: To TLousky: Thank you for suggesting cgcookie. I am enjoying their tutorials!

Comment: Usually stuff like this is done by sculpting.  Then you can use soft body physics and/or add some extra bones to the rig (protruding from the spine) to get the skin to move realistically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Since it seems you found it useful, I am re-posting my comment as an answer:*

For the dimpling use a combination of a Displace Modifier and some bump in your material. For the skin material add an SSS Shader to your glossy+diffuse mix. A skin texture image into the Diffuse color input would help too. For the ripple you can use a Cloth sim like in [this tutorial](http://youtube.com/watch?v=e1lHca7I3So). or a Soft Body sim like in [this tutorial](http://youtube.com/watch?v=KuzIDG4z_Gk). Finally [here is a Soft Body tutorial specifically for belly ripple](http://youtube.com/watch?v=DiO52a-iK_k), lol - although it is in Spanish. Good luck!